# "env: bash: No such file or directory" trying to run gradle on Jenkins on Mac Mini

Tags: android, bash, jenkins, gradle, env

I've installed the gradle plugin on Jenkins, but whenever I try to run a gradle task, I get the error:

```
env: bash: No such file or directory
```

It's weird, I don't get this error when I run the same task from the terminal at the same location.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the $PATH in that setup? Betcha it's not the same as your $PATH

Comment: Thanks Glenn, it does indeed look like my PATH from terminal is different from my PATH from Jenkins, and the path to bash (/bin/bash) wasn't in my Jenkins path. I've set the path and am restarting the box now to see if it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glenn essentially answered my question above in his comment. My PATH in Jenkins was different from my PATH from the terminal. I went and updated my /etc/launchd.conf file and added /bin to the PATH and Jenkins was able to find bash.